# Canvas size as a bounding box of the contained elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing a user control that is a view for an arrangement of shapes, which can be moved around and zoomed with the mouse, altogether or individually. The user control contains a single "Root" canvas to which the shapes are added, and the render transform of which determines its position and size in the view.

What I would like to be able is to set the background of the canvas to a rectangle that encloses all its contained shapes. Is this possible ? Of course I can set the Width and Height properties but they seem to count from the origin only. But the shapes can as well be placed at negative coordinates relative to the canvas' origin so the background rectangle of the canvas would have to start at negative coordinates also.

```
Canvas cnv = new Canvas();
// show the canvas' dimensions
cnv.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;

for (int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = -5; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle();
        cnv.Children.Add(newRectangle);
        newRectangle.Width = 7;
        newRectangle.Height = 7;
        newRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Green;
        Canvas.SetTop(newRectangle, j * 10);
        Canvas.SetLeft(newRectangle, i * 10);
    }
}

// these are the right bounding dimensions, but with the wrong origin
cnv.Width = 107;
cnv.Height = 107;

// nothing available like that?
// cnv.Left = -50;
// cnv.Top= -50;
```

Of course, if everything fails, I could just add another rectangle for the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canvas is transparent so why not stack it on top of a rectangle in a grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Lime" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" />
    <Canvas />
</Grid>
```

Or if it realy has to look like a border:

```
<Border Background="Lime" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5">
    <Canvas />
</Border>
```

Comment: Sure, that would be the fallback solution. But one reason for me asking was also: if I don't have the freedom to set the Canvas' top/left borders, then I have the feeling this is probably a sign that I am using Canvas for something it is not made for... Is there a problem with placing children at negative coordinates?

Comment: In both my solutions the border doesn't need to know the coordinate system of the canvas. So in a way these are much easier. Do note however that when you place items in the canvas at negative coordinates that they will be placed outside of the canvas. The coordinate system of the canvas is not adjustable except by adjusting all its children's coordinates.

Comment: If there is no other drawback of negative child coordinates that would be okay for me. Being outside the canvas is no problem because my user control sets ClipToBounds = true and it also doesn't impair visibility since I can move/scale the canvas until all items are visible.